# How to give Folder Permission for IIS User in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, folder-permissions

I need to give Folder Permission for IIS User.
Actually I wrote code like this..

```
public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights,AccessControlType ControlType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(
        new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(objUser, Rights, ControlType));
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

I calling this above method like this...

```
void givepermission()
{
    DirectoryInfo a = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/resources"));
    AddDirectorySecurity(Server.MapPath("~/"), "IUSR", FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow);
}
```

But Locally its working.  When going server not working.

Instead of IUSR I tried following Account Names but that also not working ..

IIS_IUSRS
IIS_WPG
Network Service
Everyone
etc..

Instead IIS_IUSRS. I Tried like this also...

```
System.Environment.MachineName + "\\IIS_IUSRS"

IIS_IUSRS_System.Environment.MachineName

System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\IIS_IUSRS"

etc..
```

but this also not working, but it's throwing 
"Some or all identity references could not be translated"

**Note:**I Don't want to set the Permission Manually

Please can some one help me with this..?

Comment: Does the user account the application is running under have permissions to set such permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) article:

> IIS introduces a new security feature in Service Pack 2 (SP2) of
>   Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista. It's called Application Pool
>   Identities. Application Pool Identities allow you to run Application
>   Pools under a unique account without having to create and manage
>   domain or local accounts. The name of the Application Pool account
>   corresponds to the name of the Application Pool.

[Here](http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx)'s a good explanation of what happens:

> In Windows 7, IIS application pool isolation was taken yet to a
>   different level. The new change introduced in IIS7 (Windows Server
>   2008) was a new option to run your application pool as AppPoolIdentiy.
>   However, the default for an application pool identity in IIS7 remained
>   the same – NetworkService. In IIS7.5, AppPoolIdentiy becomes a
>   default. Thus, scripts previously expecting permissions for their
>   application pool identity to be set to “NT Service\NetworkService”
>   will now have to set permissions (ACLs) for “IIS AppPool\” – the user account created for each new application pool.
>
> Thus, to set permissions for the DefaultAppPool, **the scripts will
>   need to set ACLs for “IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool”**.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply..but i used even IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool also ...but still not working..

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void FolderPermission(String accountName, String folderPath)
    {
        try
        {

            FileSystemRights Rights;

            //What rights are we setting? Here accountName is == "IIS_IUSRS"

            Rights = FileSystemRights.FullControl;
            bool modified;
            var none = new InheritanceFlags();
            none = InheritanceFlags.None;

            //set on dir itself
            var accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(accountName, Rights, none, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow);
            var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            var dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
            dSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, accessRule, out modified);

            //Always allow objects to inherit on a directory 
            var iFlags = new InheritanceFlags();
            iFlags = InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit;

            //Add Access rule for the inheritance
            var accessRule2 = new FileSystemAccessRule(accountName, Rights, iFlags, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);
            dSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, accessRule2, out modified);

            dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```